# what is the complexity of the operation set(list())

Tags: set, time-complexity

Can you help me with finding out the complexity of the set function in python.

```
A = [1,2,1,2,4]
A = set(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's linear, that is it takes `O(n)` time, where `n` is the number of elements in the list `A`, as you can infer from [the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Comment: This has time complexity information as well. [data structure complexities](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt)